How to update "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER[sdk=iphoneos*]" via Fastlane?
Using the fastlane function update_project_provisioning everything is updated correctly except "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER[sdk=iphoneos*]". How can I update it?
I also use the match function in my pipeline, but it does not change the configuration of the project.pbxproj file.

Can you share your update_project_provisioning action?
